# SupaBase PostgrestException(message: JWT expired, code: PGRST301, details: Unauthorized, hint: null)

Tags: flutter, supabase

I have a Flutter app with supaBase backend. when I want to read data from tables for the first 3 times calling the database it's all good working but after 3 times I am facing this error :

```
PostgrestException(message: JWT expired, code: PGRST301, details: Unauthorized, hint: null)
```

the way I implement reading data is

```
   Future<List<BrandModel>> getBrands() async {
    List<BrandModel> data = [];
    try {
      var response = await supabase.from('brand').select();
      data = (response as List).map((e) => BrandModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return data;
  }
```

the main function is :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //? widget bindings
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //? initializing supa
  await Supabase.initialize(
      url: AppConsts.supaBaseURL, anonKey: AppConsts.anonKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your supabase setting.

Setting > List menu on left side > Authentication > Scroll down to Advanced Settings.

Change your duration of Access Tokens (JWT) expiry time based on your need.

[image]